# Charts.js value dependent coloring

Tags: javascript, charts

I was wondering, if it's possible to make Charts.js change fill color depending if point value is positive or negative.

I'm making my accountant system for my friends new company, and I have chart that shows financial status in a chart, and if my earnings go below 0, it should show it as red, and if it goes to positive, it should show it as green.

So is it even possible in Charts.js to change chart fill color depending on which side the chart is on from x axis?

Here's a link to photoshopped image of the result I need to get.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7SJJ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible.

You would have to inspect your data when returned from your call to the server. Inspect the value if <0 then add Red to the Array and if > 0 then Green.

Something Like :

```
const backgroundColours = [];

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (result[i].valueName <0) {
                backgroundColours.push(red());  
        } else {
        backgroundColours.push(green());
        }
 }


const red= function() {
    return 'rgb(255,0,0)';
};

const green = function() {
    return 'rgb(0,255,0)';
};
```

Then as part of your chart definition just do something like :

```
data: {
                labels: .....,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        backgroundColor: backgroundColours,
                        data: ....,
                    },
                    ],
            }, ....
```